# How to gracefully handle "verification required" in in-app purchases

Tags: swift, in-app-purchase

Once in a while I see that the alert appears saying that verification is required to make a purchase.

When user taps "Continue" the AppStore opens the payment information view and after filling in the CVV it redirects user back to the app.

However at this point `SKPaymentQueue` reports an error saying "Cannot connect to iTunes store". The purchase automatically handles in background then.

This is a production environment and it's really hard to catch and test this kind of event and I am not able to reproduce this kind of scenario in sandbox.

Does anyone know how to gracefully handle this scenario so we don't show an error to the user?

[image]